# Laravel/npm | Установка bootstrap 5. Компиляция из resources в public

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, npm

Пытаюсь установить bootstrap 5 с помощью вот таких команд:
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install
npm run dev

Но ничего не происходит. Из resources ничего не компилируется в public. Кучу раз переустанавливал проект, пробовал разные версии php, но ничего. Может кто способен помочь?
[image: Терминал]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Для тех кто разбирается в пакетных менеджерах, то есть те кто может мне помочь, для них на этой картинке вся необходимая информация без которой наверное никак. По вашему мне стоит ctr+c,ctr+v копировать консоль в тему? Если функция загрузки изображений не нужна тут, зачем она тогда вообще на сайте

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу, php 8

Comment: Как хорошо что я нашел это запись, "возился" полдня! Сначала 10 Лав на пхп8 хотел запустить (еще по урокам 2-3 летней давности) ничего не вышло! Но в связке Лав8 и пхп 7.4 заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Спустя пару часов нашёл решение. Оказывается что на версии php 8+ оно либо не работает вообще, либо(что скорее всего) работает по другому. Откатился до 7.4 и всё прекрасно заработало